# Href="#" works in localhost but not in public

Tags: html

I´m trying to implement a Login session in my website, but, i´m having trouble with this part:

```
    <ul class="tab-group">
      <li class="tab"><a href="#signup">Criar uma conta</a></li>
      <li class="tab active"><a href="#login">Possuo uma conta</a></li>
    </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">

     <div id="login" name="login">
      <h1>Bem vindo! ;)</h1>

      <form action="principal.php" method="post" autocomplete="new-password">

        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          E-mail<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input class="tudomin" type="email" required autocomplete="new-password" name="email"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Senha<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password" required autocomplete="new-password" name="password"/>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <p class="forgot"><a href="forgot.php">Esqueceu sua senha?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block" name="login" />Log In</button>

      </form>

    </div>

    <div id="signup" name="signup">
      <h1>Crie uma conta, é rapidinho!</h1>
      <h5 style="color: red; background-color: white;">Sua conta será confirmada via SMS.</h5>
      <br/>
      <h6 style="color: red; background-color: white;">É necessário um telefone celular válido!</h6>

      <form action="principal.php" method="post" autocomplete="new-password">

      <div class="top-row">
        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Nome<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input class="primaiusc" type="text" required autocomplete="new-password" name='firstname' />
        </div>

        <div class="field-wrap">
          <label>
            Sobrenome<span class="req">*</span>
          </label>
          <input class="primaiusc" style="text-transform: capitalize;" type="text"required autocomplete="new-password" name='lastname' />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
  <!--     <input type="email"required autocomplete="off" name='email' style="display: none" />  Campo fake -->
        <label>
          E-mail<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input class="tudomin" type="email"required autocomplete="new-password" name='email' />
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Celular<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="text" required autocomplete="new-password" name='telefone' id='telefone' maxlength="15"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label style="left: calc(8.6em + 1vw)">
          Data de Nascimento<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="date" required autocomplete="new-password" name='nascimento'/>
      </div>

       <div class="field-wrap">
        <label style="left: calc(8.6em + 1vw)">
          Instituição de Ensino<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <select name="instituicao" class="req" required>
                <option value="" disabled selected hidden></option>
          <?php while($rowinst = mysqli_fetch_array($resultinst))
                {
                    $datarowinst = '<option value="'.$rowinst['id'].'">'.$rowinst['instituicao'].'</option>';
                    echo $datarowinst;
                }
            ?>
        </select>
      </div>        

       <div class="field-wrap">
        <label style="left: calc(8.6em + 1vw)">
          Período de Estudo<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <select name="periodo" class="req" required>
                <option value=""  disabled selected hidden></option>
                <option value="Manhã">Manhã</option>
                <option value="Tarde">Tarde</option>
                <option value="Noite">Noite</option>
                <option value="Integral">Integral</option>

        </select>
      </div>   

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Senha<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password"required autocomplete="new-password" name='password'/>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="button button-block" name="register" />Criar conta!</button>

      </form>

    </div>
```

It supose to change the screen when a click on href="#signup" or href="#login".
And it works just fine on localhost but, for some reason it just doesn´t work on public. Any ideas?

To see what i´m talking about, this is the link:
https://www.educacaosc.com.br/Login/principal.php

Thanks!

Comment: Press F12 and see errors: Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.educacaosc.com.br/Login/principal.php' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: _"Firefox can't find the server at www.educacaosc.com.br."_

Comment: That´s awesome! If I remove the https it really works. I had no ideia i could press F12 and see it. Now I just need to know how to not load over https. Thank you very much!